# Problems in creating graphs using dataplot

Tags: graphs, datatool, database

I have four simple databases:

**db1**

```
dy,volume
2009,120000
2010,160000
2011,400000
2012,650000
2013,1000000
2014,1500000
```

**db2**

```
dy,volume
2009,400000
2010,500000
2011,1600000
2012,2200000
2013,2500000
2014,4000000
```

**db3**

```
dy,volume
2009,100000
2010,120000
2011,150000
2012,160000
2013,400000
2014,1000000
```

**db4**

```
dy,volume
2009,250000
2010,400000
2011,750000
2012,900000
2013,1400000
2014,3000000
```

And with these four files I like to create a simple graphical representation like [**this**](http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation). I am using `dataplot` package for this purpose. And here is my source file:

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{dataplot}
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{db1}{db1.csv}
\DTLloaddb{db2}{db2.csv}
\DTLloaddb{db3}{db3.csv}
\DTLloaddb{db4}{db4.csv}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\DTLplot{db1,db2,db3,db4}{x=dy,y=volume,
width=3in,height=3in,style=lines,legend,legendlabels={Legend1,Legend2,Legend3,Legend4},
xlabel={Year},ylabel={Volume},box,
xticpoints={2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014}
}

\caption{A simple graph}

\end{document}
```

But, I am getting this error over and over saying:

```
Package datatool Error: Can't assign \DTLthisX : there is no key `dy' in database `db1'.
```

If there is someone who could help me out in this regard, either pointing my error or any useful information to handle this.

One more question:

As my database contains huge numbers (i.e., `> 100000`), how can I manage to show this on `y-axis` as `100k` and so on. Where `k` denotes a `kilo`. Any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `dataplot`, but here is an example of what you can do with `pgfplots`; I've only plotted the first two sets of data, but you can easily build on the existing code to include the last two.

Regarding the "huge numbers" on the y-axis, whether you end up using `dataplot` or `pgfplots`, I strongly advise you to multiply them by 10^{-6} and specify that factor in the y-label; the numbers become much easier to read (nobody likes to count loads of zeros). However, it's really up to you.

I've used `filecontents` to simulate the existence of your .cvs files.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{db1.cvs}
    dy,volume
    2009,120
    2010,160
    2011,400
    2012,650
    2013,1000
    2014,1500
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{db2.cvs}
    dy,volume
    2009,400
    2010,500
    2011,1600
    2012,2200
    2013,2500
    2014,4000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=\textwidth,
        ylabel shift=1ex,
        enlargelimits=0.13,
        tick align=outside,
        legend style={cells={anchor=west},legend pos=north east},
        xtick={2009,2010,...,2014},
        xticklabels={2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014},
        ytick={500,1000,...,4000},
        yticklabels={500k,1000k,1500k,2000k,2500k,3000k,3500k,4000k},
        xlabel=\textbf{year},
        ylabel=\textbf{volume}
        ]
        \addplot[mark=none,blue] table [x=dy, y=volume, col sep=comma] {db1.cvs};
        \addlegendentry{db1}
        \addplot[mark=none,red] table [x=dy, y=volume, col sep=comma] {db2.cvs};
         \addlegendentry{db2}   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to load a external file (instead of preparing hard-coded file), on which basis the lines would be generated.

Comment: @Cylian You can load external files as `\addplot file {db1.dat};` @Jubobs +1 for nice answer, but it would be nice if the years were written as `2009` not `2,009`

Comment: @Ipsen I'll fix it right away.