# Insert dynamic graphs

Tags: graphics, diagrams

Is it possible to insert dynamic graphs into your LaTeX document?

For example, let's say I want to add ABC Enterprise's turnover into my LaTeX document for each month.  Could I do something like this @{turnover, Jan=£1000.00, Feb=£1200.00, Mar=£400.00} and then use that data to automatically render/draw a bar chart?

Or is the only way to get a graph into my LaTeX document via inserting images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to do it with LaTeX code than it would be probably [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). To me it is often faster to use an external program like [`gnuplot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot). The package [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) is a tool to implement graphs with the correct typesettings. See [Problems in creating graphs using dataplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105657/problems-in-creating-graphs-using-dataplot).

### Example

Could you give a minimal example of your database? Your procedure is dependent on the shape of the database. You maybe like to follow [How typeset a numeric table from a CSV file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24256/how-typeset-a-numeric-table-from-a-csv-file).

### Compiling

Remember that you mostly do not want to compile the graphs everytime you compile the latex-main file.

Comment: `pgfplots` and `datatool` can do that pretty conveniently. Here are many examples of it [pgfplots tagged questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots) , [datatool tagged questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datatool)